# node js mysql save from select the data to a var

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I have this query:

```
var sql = "SELECT user FROM users WHERE user = '" + req.body.user + "'";
```

Suppose I have in the database a row with the user: babushka and 
the req.body.user is also: babushka. This query will bring me the answer: 
`{user: 'babushka'}`.

```
connection.query(sql, function (err, result) {
    if (err) {
        throw err;
    }
    console.log(result);
});
```

But, I am trying to save only the babushka to a var. How can I do it?

Comment: `var user = result.user;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your result is a Javascript [Object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects). You can get the `user` property like this:

```
 connection.query(sql, function (err, result) {
        if (err) {
            throw err;
        }
        var user =result.user;
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Easy, just access the `user` property from the `result` object.

Also, **[don't concatenate raw input from users into your SQL](https://xkcd.com/327/)!** Using parameter binding like shown to safely avoid [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) easily:

```
var sql = "SELECT user FROM users WHERE user = ?";

connection.query(sql, [req.body.user], function (err, result) {
    if (err) {
        throw err;
    }
    var user = result.user;
    console.log(user);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

From your query, you can easily get the answer from result [object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/JSON). 
You can use

```
console.log(result.user);
```

That is, your entire code will be like this

```
var sql = "SELECT user FROM users WHERE user = '" + req.body.user + "'";
  connection.query(sql, function (err, result) {
    if (err) {
        console.log('db fetch error',error);
        throw err;
    }
   else {
   let user =result.user;
   console.log('user=>',user);
    }

});
```